# Return result set using Weakly-typed cursor Variable

Tags: db2, db2-luw, database-cursor

```
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE return_result_set ( )
    LANGUAGE SQL
    SPECIFIC return_result_set                   
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
rrs: BEGIN
    
    DECLARE rs_cur CURSOR WITH RETURN
        FOR SELECT *
            FROM dummytable;
    OPEN rs_cur;                                  
                                            
END rrs
```

I can return result set using cursor by using above stored procedure, but I want to use [cursor variable (Weakly-typed)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/c0053413.html) in my stored procedure as the select query and table are going to vary based on a condition. Sample code [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/c0053426.html)  seems to be for different use case..

How to return a result set using a Cursor Variable?

Comment: In what way exactly the example to which you linked does not work for you?

Comment: Your question shows a static-SQL statement that is used for a cursor. Do you know which programming language will __consume__ your result-set?  It matters, because if you __really__ want to use a weakly-typed cursor variable then only an SQL caller can use such a cursor. It's possible you just need to use dynamic SQL instead of static-SQL in your procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Try this as is:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON@

BEGIN
  DECLARE V_C1 CURSOR;
  DECLARE V_I INT;
  
  DECLARE PROCEDURE L_PROC(OUT LP_C1 CURSOR) 
    BEGIN 
      -- Dynamic cursor
      --DECLARE V_STMT VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT 'SELECT * FROM (VALUES 1) T(I)';
      --PREPARE V_S1 FROM V_STMT;
      --SET LP_C1 = CURSOR FOR V_S1;

      -- Static cursor
      SET LP_C1 = CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM (VALUES 1) T(I);

      OPEN LP_C1;
    END;
 
  CALL L_PROC(V_C1);
  FETCH V_C1 INTO V_I;
  CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('I: ' || V_I);
  CLOSE V_C1;
END@

SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF@
```

Comment: Thank you for your response... as mao suggested , the caller of this stored procedure is non sql caller (Java and Express Js). In that case can't i use either of week /strongly typed cursors? In that case how can i return result set preferably without using dynamic sql..

Comment: I can't understand, why you need cursor variable and why you can't use the code you provided above. You may declare whatever number of different cursors with static sql inside, but open and return conditionally only one of them. You may even declare a cursor needed only conditionally as well.